# sql query to find records not in other table

Tags: sql

I have a table `plist` with a column `list`, which contains comma separated ids (1,2,3,4). I want the record of those members whose id is not in the comma separated list.

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server, MySQL etc.

Comment: The only valid answer should be "redesign your DB schema and read about normalization"

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to split the comma seperated list into a table and then search against it.

Here is the code to split the string:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowID int, Layout varchar(200))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,'1,2,3,4')

;WITH SplitSting AS
(
    SELECT
        RowID,LEFT(Layout,CHARINDEX(',',Layout)-1) AS Part
            ,RIGHT(Layout,LEN(Layout)-CHARINDEX(',',Layout)) AS Remainder
        FROM @YourTable
        WHERE Layout IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Layout)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        RowID,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)-1)
            ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(',',Remainder))
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        RowID,Remainder,null
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)=0
)
SELECT RowID,part FROM SplitSting ORDER BY RowID
```

Comment: Which DB server are you using?